# Remove low / zero variance genes

Tags: r, row, variance

```
library(matrixStats) #rowVars

read_vars <- rowVars(raw_counts)
raw_counts <- raw_counts[which(read_vars > 1e-10),]
dim(raw_counts)
```

Above is the chunk in R where I am trying to remove zero variance genes from data raw_counts.
However, after executing the chunk below is the error pop ups.

```
Error in MatrixGenerics:::.load_next_suggested_package_to_search(x) :
Failed to find a rowVars() method for data.frame objects.
```

Please suggest any alternative option for rowVar?

Comment: As the error says, the function doesn't work on data frames - [it is for matrices](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/matrixStats/versions/0.63.0/topics/rowVars). So you might try `read_vars <- rowVars(as.matrix(raw_counts))`.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  You maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimal reproducible example. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.  here, we would need a (sample of) your data and an indication of which packages you are using.

Comment: OK, I'll add as an answer in that case.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to convert the data frame to a matrix, which is required for `rowVars` to work.

```
read_vars <- rowVars(as.matrix(raw_counts))
```